# Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code254

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I am using Mac. I have tried to read and implement the solution from this thread, but it doesnt work.
[Firebase deploy errors starting with non-zero exit code (space in project path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429390/firebase-deploy-errors-starting-with-non-zero-exit-code-space-in-project-path)

I get errors when deploying the code to firebase:

> i  deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%"
>   run lint npm ERR! path
>   /Users/muchammadagunglaksana/Desktop/tsCobaDoangCloudFunction/%RESOURCE_DIR%/package.json
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR!
>   enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/muchammadagunglaksana/Desktop/tsCobaDoangCloudFunction/%RESOURCE_DIR%/package.json'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/muchammadagunglaksana/.npm/_logs/2018-09-07T09_10_49_146Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
>   exit code254
>   [image]

in `firebase.json` I have tried to modify and use:

```
"npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
```

[image]

but i still get the error message like the picture above, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%RESOURCE_DIR%` is a Windows syntax. You should use `$RESOURCE_DIR` as you are on Mac.

Comment: what to do when we are using linux

Answer (score 4):

reinitialize your project

```
firebase init
```