# Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have been struggling with firebase deploy issue for quite a few hours now , but nothing seems to be working
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429390/firebase-deploy-errors-starting-with-non-zero-exit-code-space-in-project-path) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219322/error-functions-predeploy-error-command-terminated-with-non-zero-exit-code254) but no luck .

**this is what i am stuck at:**

```
  13:37  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "C:\Users\r\Desktop\cfnc\functions" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "C:\\Users\\r\\Desktop\\cfnc\\functions" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "C:\\Users\\r\\Desktop\\cfnc\\functions" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

does this mean i am missing some packages in firebase-tools? i have also installed the firebase-tools multiple times , tried pretty much every thing in above mentioned links but nothing seems to be working

Comment: What Node version are you running locally? This is usually a result of using syntax features unsupported by your current Node version.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh i am using v14.16.0