# Hello I am getting error in deploying the function in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

.eslintrx.js

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

index.js

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.onConversationCreated;
onConversationCreated = functions.firestore.document("Conversations/chatID").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    let data = snapshot.data();
    let chatID = context.params.chatID;
    if (data) {
      let members = data.members;
      for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
        let currentUserID = members[index];
        let remainingUserIDs = members.filter((u= string) => u !== currentUserID);
        remainingUserIDs.forEach(async (m= string) => {
          try {
            let _doc = await admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(m).get();
            let userData = _doc.data();
            if (userData) {
              return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(currentUserID).collection("Conversations").doc(m).create({
                "chatId": chatID,
                "image": userData.image,
                "name": userData.name,
                "unseenCount": 0,
              });
            }
            return null;
          } catch (e) {
            return null;
          }
        });
      }
    } return null;
  });
```

Error I getting:

```
C:\Users\TOHID\Desktop\chat_firebase_function>firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'chatapp-1b389'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\TOHID\Desktop\chat_firebase_function\functions
> eslint .


C:\Users\TOHID\Desktop\chat_firebase_function\functions\index.js
  15:52  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1`enter code here`
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TOHID\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-30T16_54_32_266Z-debug.log
events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\TOHID\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\TOHID\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\TOHID\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\TOHID\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

Comment: Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429390/firebase-deploy-errors-starting-with-non-zero-exit-code-space-in-project-path) out. Looks like the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation as you so I leave my quick solution for you.
"run lint" while predeploying causes error, `Unexpected token =>`  but it's not an error, as we all know.

**Solution**

1. After Cleaning out the `.eslintrx.js`, it will work.
2. Remove some lines in the `firebase.json` file.

   in `firebase.json` file,

```
    ...
      "functions": {
        "predeploy": [
          "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"  << DELETE THIS LINE
        ]
      }
```

- If you use Windows, `\"$RESOURCE_DIR\"` should be `\"%RESOURCE_DIR%\"`

3. ⭐⭐ Add `/* eslint-disable */` on top of the `index.js`file

   (I chose this)
4. If you want to persist eslint predeploy, play with eslint config file. For example,

```
  env: {
    es6: true, -> es2017 or higher?? will it work??
    node: true,
  },
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments

5. Find more info in github thread:
   https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8126

Answer (score 2):

1.) Clean .eslintrx.js

2.) in  firebase.json file

in firebase.json file, --> delete  "npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint" this line from here

```
...
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"  
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`npm run lint -- --fix`